# Rails metasearch checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So my Project model currently contains a column named tags which are in the format of a,b,c,d,e,f,etc...  In the view, I have a form which collects checkboxes's into filters[] which I can use in the controller with params[:filters]. My question is how do I filter the projects that contains at least one of those tags?

```
def index
    @search = Project.search(params[:search])
    @projects = @search.???
end
```

I thought something like

```
@projects = Project.search(:tags_contains => params[:filters])
```

or

```
params[:filters].each do |p|
    @projects ||= @search.where(["projects.tags like ?", p])
end
```

would work, but it doesn't seem to return anything. Any advice?

Example: Let's say checkboxes a and c were checked in the form which would be contained inside the params[:filters]. I have three projects:

```
Project     | Tags
------------+------
Project 1   | a,b
Project 2   | c
Project 3   | a,c
Project 4   | d
```

In this example I would want to return Project 1,2,3 since they contain at least a or c

Comment: if your storing an instance of a project, use "@project" instead of @search.  I'm not 100% sure what you're asking can you clear up your question a little.  Are you looking to find a project with a specific tag in it?

Comment: Added an example. Hope that clarifies my question, sorry

Comment: How are you handling the project to tag relationship is it a has_many ?

Comment: Tags are just strings inside a Project. I didn't create a model for them.

Comment: Is it an array?  How do you add a new tag to an already existing row

Comment: It's just a string of tags separated by commas. I don't expect tags to be changing often, but if they do I'm sure someone could just edit the tags string. I think I figured out my own question though. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using the squeel gem...

```
params[:filters].each do |p|
     @projects ||= @search.where(["projects.tags like ?", "%#{p}%"])
end
```